# A question about type rule

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory

I realized that almost no one explained how to selected the type variable T1

```
 Γ ⊢ e1 : T1 -> T  ,  Γ ⊢ e2 : T1
 -------------------------------- T-APP 
 Γ ⊢ e1 e2 : T
```

when doing type checking (from bottom to top).

So, the question is how T1 is introduced? Is there any condition about T1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"T1" is obtained from typing context by doing derivation on the right branch of application rule. I worked on some type checking examples and concluded that.

Answer (score 4):

`T1` is a schematic variable. Every consistent substitution of `T1` with a type produces an instance of the rule. In a simple enough system, the inference rules can be used directly as the blueprint for a type-checking algorithm. In languages with richer type systems, type-checking algorithms become more complex or even undecidable (which is not a desirable features). Let me give an example where I type-check the program using a simple derivation.

Let's say I have the following program I wish to type-check:

```
(lambda x: nat. x = 0)(4)
```

First, we can deduce that `4 : nat` by using the usual typing rules for natural numbers, which I will not reproduce here. Then we type-check the lambda abstraction with following derivation (I apologize for the sloppy latex):

$$ \underline{x : nat ⊢ x: nat \quad x: nat ⊢ 0 : nat} $$
$$ \underline{x : nat ⊢ x = 0 : bool}$$
$$ \underline{\lambda x: nat. \ x = 0 : nat \to bool} $$

Finally, using the application rules:

$$ \underline{\lambda x: nat. \ x = 0 : nat \to bool \quad 4 : nat} $$
$$ (\lambda x: nat. \ x = 0)(4) : bool $$

Note that type-checking is much simpler when we're working in a type system without subtyping, in that ever expression is monomorphic. The typing rules are *syntax-directed*. That is, the structure of the program dictates the type of every expression.

Comment: It would be great if you could make your derivation look standard(with horizontal lines), I am having difficulty on reading it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the expression `e2` (and `e1`) is and what other type rules are in the type system.

Basically, the `Γ ⊢ e2 : T1` part of the type rule says:

> If there is a rule in the type system, which assigns the type `T1` to the expression `e2` in the environment `Γ` …

If you can also find a rule that assigns the type `T1 -> T` to `e1`, then you can use the type assignment from the conclusion.

Comment: You are right in practice, but this kind of judgments doesn't specify how you actually type check a program. They're done top-down. If you want to see a better formalization of how type checking works, check out "bidirectional type checking".

Comment: Typing rules are not algorithms. They tell you what is allowed, but not what to do.

Comment: still, I did not understand how do we know what T1 is at the moment when we are applying T-APP rule.